# Coordinating dependent microservices in java

Tags: java, microservices, orchestration

I have to coordinate 5 separate microservices e.g. A,B,C,D,E

I need to create a coordinator which might monitor a queue for new jobs for A. If A completes ok then a rest request should be sent to B then if everything is ok (happy path) then C is called all the way down to E.

However B,C etc might fail for one reason or another e.g. end point is down or credentials are insufficient causing the flow to fail at a particular stage. I'd like to be able to create something that could check the status of failed job and rerun again e.g. lets try B again, ok now it works the flow would then continue.

Any tips or advice for patterns / frameworks to do this. I'd like something fairly simple and not over complex.

I've already looked briefly at Netflix Conductor / Camunda but ideally I'd like something a bit less complex.

Thanks
W

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

> Any tips or advice for patterns / frameworks to do this. I'd like something fairly simple and not over complex.

What you describe is the good ol' domain of A,B,C,D and E. Because the dependencies and engagement rules between the letters are complex enough, it's good to create a dedicated service for this domain. It could be as simple as this overarching service just being triggered by queue events.

The only other alternative is to do more on the client side and organize the service calls from there. But that isn't feasible in every domain for security reasons or other issues.

And since it sounds like you already got an event queue going, I'll not recommend one (Kafka).

Answer (score 0):

One way apart from Camunda, Conductor  is to send a event from Service A on some Messaging Queue (eg. lets say kafka ) which provides at least once delivery semantics.

Then write a consumer which receive the event and do the orchestration part (talking to service B,C,D,E).

As these all operations needs to be idempotent.First before starting orchestration create a RequestAgg. for the event from A and keep updating its state to represent where you reach in your orchestration journey.

Now even if the other services are down or your node goes down. This should either reach the end or you should write functions to rollback as well.

And to check the states and debug , you could see the read model of RequestAgg.